# dot product of 2-D array and 1-D array is different from matrix and 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I used the numpy [dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) function to calculate the product of a 2D and a 1D array. I noticed that when the 2D array is of type [matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) while the 1D array is of type [ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), the result returned by the `dot` function is not the same as when I pass it a 2D array of type `ndarray`.

**Question**: Why are the results different?

**Short example**

```py
import numpy as np
a=[[1,2],
   [3,4],
   [5,6]]
e=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array(a)
print("Ndarrray:%s"%(type(b)))
print(b)
print("Dim of ndarray %d"%(np.ndim(b)))
be=np.dot(b,e)
print(be)
print("Dim of array*array %d\n"%(np.ndim(be)))

c=np.mat(a)
print("Matrix:%s"%(type(c)))
print(c)
print("Dim of matrix %d"%(np.ndim(c)))
ce=np.dot(c,e)
print(ce)
print("Dim of matrix*array %d"%(np.ndim(ce)))
```

```
Ndarrray:<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
Dim of ndarray 2
[ 5 11 17]
Dim of array*array 1

Matrix:<class 'numpy.matrix'>
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
Dim of matrix 2
[[ 5 11 17]]
Dim of matrix*array 2
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, for the matrix class:

> Note: 
>   It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
>   algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the
>   future.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

That's because the first element in the dot product is of matrix type, and therefore you receive a matrix as output. But if you use the `shape method` to get the "real" size of your matrix you get a coherent result:

```
import numpy as np
a=[[1,2],
   [3,4],
   [5,6]]
e=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array(a)
print("Ndarrray:%s"%(type(b)))
print(b)
print("Dim of ndarray %d"%(np.ndim(b)))
be=np.dot(b,e)
print(be)
print("Dim of array*array %d\n"%(np.ndim(be)))

c=np.mat(a)
print("Matrix:%s"%(type(c)))
print(c)
print("Dim of matrix %d"%(np.ndim(c)))
ce=np.dot(c,e)
print(ce)
print("Dim of matrix*array %d"%(np.ndim(ce))) 
print("Dim of matrix*array ",(ce.shape)) # -> ('Dim of matrix*array ', (1, 3))
print(type(ce)) # <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
```

You have a matrix of shape `(1,3)`, which is in fact a vector (dim 1, because you have 1 row and 3 columns)

Basically, to get the dimensions of matrix instance you should use `shape`, not `ndim`

To make it more clear, if you define an empty matrix you get as default always 2 dims:

```
c=np.mat([])
print(c.ndim) # 2
```

Probably it has been intended in this way because we start to talk of a Matrix when we have at least 2-dims